# Using Brent algorithm to find the root of a function f with an initial guess, but without intervals [a,b] s.t. f(a)f(b)<0

Tags: c++, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, fminsearch

I would like to know how to use Brent algorithm if no opposite signs can be provided.

For example, in the [C++ library of Brent algorithm](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/brent/brent.html,), the root-finding procedure that implements Brent’s method has to be used, following the [header file](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/brent/brent.hpp), in the form of

double zero ( double a, double b, double t, func_base& f );
where a, b satisfies the condition of opposite signs:  `f(a).f(b) < 0`

In my problem setting, I need to find the root(s) of  a *black-box* function f. An initial guess is provided but no endpoints a,b, such that f(a) f(b)<0 are provided  It seems that in Matlab there is a function *fmin* that only needs an initial guess. I would like to know how to do this using C++, in particular, using the implementation of Brent such as the one linked above?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Matlab apparently uses the ['golden section search'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) in part of its `fmin` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumptions that

- *f* is a *black-box*, i.e. it can be evaluated but no information on its shape is known whatsoever.
- You have to use a method that requires a priori knowledge of an interval [*a*,*b*] which brackets a root of *f* (assuming *f* is continuous).

I think your only option is to make a preliminary search for two valid points *a* and *b*. 
This can be done in a number of ways. The most simple-minded could be to run a linear search (with some prescribed step) starting from your initial guess, which can be repeated with a finer step if it turns out unsuccessful. If *f* is not too "weird" a simple method should do.

Clearly, some basic clue on the properties of *f* is always necessary, for example that it actually has a root and that it is continuos, differentiable, etc.. All root finding methods (gradient descent, Newton-Raphson, bisection, etc.) assume some basic properties of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Without doing exhaustive search (and in the case of real valued function, you cannot, since the value of `x` is [uncountable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set)), there is no way to really guarantee finding the root if such exist.

One heuristic approach to address the problem is using [**gradient descent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent), in order to minimze (/maximize) the value of the function, until you find a local minimum (/maximum) or until you find a root.

The problem with this approach is you can get stuck in a local minimum (/maximum) before finding the root, and "think" there is no root, even if one does exist.